# Visual Studio 2012 express - совместная работа

Tags: c#, git, svn

Задача: совместная работа над одним C# проектом двух человек с двух компьютеров.

Условия: никогда прежде не работал с git/svn и прочим. IDE - Visual Studio 2012 Express

Вопрос: каким инструментом мне воспользоваться, чтобы как можно быстрее и проще начать совместную работу над проектом?

Comment: Чтобы быстрее начать — не пользуйтесь source control'ом вообще. Если хотите писать по-серьёзному, выучите сначала git flow и пользуйтесь git'ом (VS 2012 вроде уже умеет).

Comment: Вообще есть "git for Visual Studio" - мне лично нравится (удобно коммитить отдельные файлы, удобно конфликты разрешать, с GitHub-ом неплохо связывается)

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то в экспресс версиях студии нельзя ставить аддоны.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, git лучшее и самое популярное решение для повсеместной разработки приложений. Не знаю как там с Visual studio Express, но точно знаю, что в Visual Studio Pro есть встроеный Team Foundation Server, который предоставляет возможности командной разработки(есть git и д.р. системы управления версиями).

Для Express(если нет Team Foundation), придется почитать про git, материал небольшой, есть достаточно информации про создание, клонирование репозитория: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh850437.aspx

Если не любитель долгих и нудных речей, тогда поможет хабр: [Git и Visual Studio: как правильно приготовить](http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/216037/)

Также сервисы хранения репозиториев:

- [GitHub](http://github.com/)
- [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/)

С ними тоже придется поучиться работать...

P.S. Git - это не так то сложно как может показаться на первый взгляд...